# Installing a whole house water filtration

Tags: water-filtration

I am planning to install a Whole House Water Filtration/Softening system. I was able to locate the manifold and find the main line coming into my house. A plumber provided me a loop using 3/4 inch PEX. Am I correct that should use 1 inch connections to the filtration system?[image: Main Tap]

The White Pex is my main and the Blue (to the house). The plumber basically made another manifold. I'm on a concrete slab. My plan is to transition from this PEX to PVC. I plan to cover this section with a piece of plywood. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I would find out what size the softener and filter system is I have installed several and they were 3/4”. If you jump back to 1” then drop to 3/4 you may have higher possible flow rates but what is the limiting factor of the filter system?

Comment: PVC is not used for interior supply lines. It has chemicals that can be toxic in drinking water, as I understand it. Continue use of the pex pipe or use copper or cpvc pipe. Cpvc is probably the easiest and cheapest way to go for a beginner as it glues together and does not require expensive fittings. However, sharkbite, tectite fittings can be used where necessary or desired on cpvc.

Comment: Ditto what @DAS said. If you look at the white PVC already in your walls, you'll see that it's printed right on there that it's not for pressurized systems. Your incoming water _is_ pressurized, anywhere from 30-100PSI. (At the higher end, there should be a pressure reducing valve `PRV` somewhere in your system because you don't want 100PSI coming out when you're washing your hands!)

Comment: Thanks a bunch all! I have a better feel for this now. I'll transition to CPVC using SharkBite and check the size information in the system I plan to buy.